# creating user_id from session on photo upload?

Tags: php, mysql, image, upload

I'm using this php photo upload script to store an image into my database.

My database has three columns: 'user_id' 'name' 'image'

It all works fine. The image is uploaded but at the moment it doesn't store the user_id and I want to try and make it so that when the user hits upload it uses their session id to store their user_id.

I've had a go at it by adding these two functions to the original mysql query:

`(user_id, image, name)` `'".$_SESSION['user_id']."',`

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Upload Image</title>
    </head>
    <body>    
        <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="file" name="image">
            <input type="submit" value="Upload">
        </form>    
<?php        
    include("includes/_config/connection.php");

    // file properties
    $file = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];

    if (!isset($file))
        echo "";    
    else {      
        $image = addslashes (file_get_contents ($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']));
        $image_name = addslashes ($_FILES['image']['name']);
        $image_size = getimagesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);

        if ($image_size == FALSE)
            echo "That's not an image.";        
        else {      
            if (!$insert = mysql_query ("INSERT INTO  ptb_img_uploads (user_id, image, name) VALUES ('', '".$_SESSION['user_id']."', '$image_name','$image')"))    
                echo "There was a problem sending the image.";      
            else    
                echo "Your image was successfully uploaded.";    
        }    
    }    
?>    
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: if you echo out `$_SESSION['user_id']` what value does it have?

Comment: it doesn't seem to be echoing out anything when i do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to start PHP session_start(), which starts the session function. You also have to set the $_SESSION['user_id'] somewhere.

Change to this code:

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Upload Image</title>
</head>
<body>

<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="image">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload">
</form>

<?php
include("includes/_config/connection.php");

// file properties
$file = $_FILES ['image'] ['tmp_name'];

if (!isset($file))
{
    echo "";
}
else
{
    $image = addslashes (file_get_contents ($_FILES ['image']['tmp_name']));
    $image_name = addslashes ($_FILES['image']['name']);
    $image_size = getimagesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);

    if($image_size == FALSE)
    {
        echo "That's not an image.";
    }
    else
    {
        if(!$insert = mysql_query ("INSERT INTO  ptb_img_uploads (user_id, image, name) VALUES ('".$_SESSION['user_id']."', '$image_name','$image')"))
        {
            echo "There was a problem sending the image.";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "Your image was successfully uploaded.";
        }
    }

}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

If that doesn't work, you could add this right above session_start:

```
session_save_path("tmp");
```

Remember to create a folder in your directory named "tmp" with chmod 777.

If you want to test if your session works, do this:

```
<?php
session_start();

$_SESSION['test_session']="this is a test session";

var_dump($_SESSION);
?>
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!$insert = mysql_query ("INSERT INTO  ptb_img_uploads (user_id, image, name) VALUES ('".$_SESSION['user_id']."', '$image', '$image_name')"))
```

Comment: first check the column names of his code! then see his values. He has assigned NULL '' to user_id and instead of three values corresponding user_id, image and name, he wrote four values! I think you can see difference in his and my code!

Answer (score 0):

You must start the session first. session_start();. After that echo $insert; and paste the query in mysql and check for error.